# Rails devise Sessions Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, controller, devise

In devise, many of the pages that teach how to accomplish certain things require editing a sessions controller. I set up devise using this https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/wiki/Tutorial-(Walkthrough) It didn't go over making a sessions controller. How do I make one. (If it's really easy i'm sorry, just give me the few simple steps)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create your Sessions Controller with `rails g controller MySessions`. Then inside of your controller change it from inheriting from `ApplicationController` to the Devise Controller like so:

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

#your session logic here

end
```

Any of the logic within that controller that you want to override you can override by calling that method and inserting your own logic. For the list of what's in that controller, you can view the code on their [Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) page. If you do not wish to override their methods you can either leave them out, or just call super.

```
def new
  super
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback @janders. BTW, is there a reason why it's `MySessions` instead of `Sessions` as in the source code? Is that a typo, or does it not matter that it's different?

Comment: The name of your controller does not matter, so long as it inherits from `Devise::SessionsController`.

Comment: ah, just realized it's inheriting from `Devise::SessionsController` and not simply `DeviseController`. That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Actually the name of the controller DOES matter. There are numerous places inside Devise which compare the current value of `controller_name` to `"sessions"`. Also, the i18n keys it uses are based off the controller name, etc. You should call your subclass just `SesssionsController`