# Rails: Rendering different views for a devise login depending on the stored location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using a bookmarklet that loads an iframe. I am using devise for authentication. If the iframe loads and tries to hit the 'bookmark' action but needs to authenticate, it obviously redirects the iframe to the sign_in path before forwarding onto the '`bookmark`' action. I want the '`sessions/new`' action (the login page) to render with a different layout at this point so that the login page fits inside the iframe. Devise uses a `render_with_scopes` method though rather than a standard render method and passing it a `:layout => 'my_iframe_layout'` option does not work. I tried taking the `render_with_scope` method out of the `lib` module file and placing it in my controller but it created errors in the stack that caused a server crash.

I think I need a sessions controller method that looks something like this:

```
    def new
    resource = build_resource
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    #test whether the destination of this request is the bookmark action (mapped to /add_site)
    if after_sign_in_path_for(resource)[0..8] == '/add_site'
      respond_with_navigational(resource, stub_options(resource)){ render_with_scope :new }
  :layout => "bookmark_layout"    
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource, stub_options(resource)){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
end
```

The only hack I thought of was to have a special authenticate method for my '`bookmark`' action that tests what the destination action is and then authenticates accordingly but that doesn't seem very DRY.

Answer (score 2):

So the complete solution was to take the `render_with_scopes` method out of it's lib file, rename it and place it in the application controller (not in the sessions controller as I did before). A `:layout => 'bookmark_layout` option was added to the method.

```
 def render_with_scope_bookmark(action, path=self.controller_path)
    if self.class.scoped_views?
      begin
        render :template => "#{devise_mapping.scoped_path}/#{path.split("/").last}/#{action}", :layout => 'bookmark_layout'
      rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
        render :template => "#{path}/#{action}", :layout => 'bookmark_layout'
      end
    else
      render :template => "#{path}/#{action}", :layout => 'bookmark_layout'
    end
  end
```

I then modified the sessions controller so that the new `render_with_scopes_bookmark` method was called when my bookmarklet was accessing the `sessions/new` action. The original `render_with_scope` method is used when the main site is accessing the action. My bookmarklet always hits the '/add_site' location so to test, I use `session[:resource_return_to]` (in my case the resource is user). `stored_location` and `after_signin_path` are methods for retrieving the final destination of the request and then resetting the `session[:resource_return_to]` variable so neither of these were suitable for testing the destination.

```
def new
    resource = build_resource
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    @location = session[:user_return_to]
    if @location == nil
      respond_with_navigational(resource, stub_options(resource)){ render_with_scope :new }
    elsif @location[0..8] == '/add_site'
      respond_with_navigational(resource, stub_options(resource)){ render_with_scope_bookmark :new }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource, stub_options(resource)){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
```

My next step will be to modify the `render_with_scopes` method to accept a layout option so that I don't have two versions of essentially the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom sessions controller and passing the desired layout [Rails devise Sessions Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854994/rails-devise-sessions-controller)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have created a custom sessions controller but I have have not found a way to set the layout of the 'new' action when it renders the view. The example above is what I would like to do, but  does not work in reality. Is there anyway that I can pass a layout option to the 'respond_with_navigational...' line?

Comment: To set the layout, look at the section titled "2.2.12.1 Specifying Layouts on a per-Controller Basis" here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: This is great. I can now set the layout for a given action but I need to set the layout based on what the stored_location or after_signin_path is. How could I do that from within my sessions controller or within a sessions helper?

Comment: You should be able to use simple `if` conditions that look at the attributes (such as `stored_location` or `after_signin_path`) and render the appropriate layout.