# Send a POST creating a session from commercial site to application site in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I want users to test my application without registering for an account. In order to do this I thought about including a link in my commercial site that would make a POST to my application site (http://app/login using devise) sending a fixed user and password, and thus creating a session. I tried with link_to with :method => 'post' but I dont know how to send the params in the POST body! Any suggestions?

I'm trying with this

```
link_to 'Blah', {:params => 'asdf'}, {:method => :post, :href => 'http://localhost:3001/login'}
```

Comment: How are you sending them the link? Via email for exemple? Because that will create a GET request, and not a POST request.

Comment: The link would be in the commercial website. You just enter the commercial application, click the link, and then you are logged in in the real application. I forgot to mention that I am using link_to with option :method => :post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass the query params, you need to put them in as part of the URL like you would for a *GET* request. Like so:

```
<%= link_to "Click Here", "/login?username=testuser&password=moojuice", :method => :post %>
```

or alternatively if you are using Rails route helpers

```
<%= link_to "Click here", login_path(:username => "testuser", :password => "moojuice"), :method => :post %>
```

I'm not exactly sure based on the original question if you will be using this link in the same Rails application as the one you are logging into. If you aren't, there is one other slight gotcha. When posting from an external site, Rails is going to most likely ignore your request because you will be missing the CSRF token that Rails automatically generates when you loads a page. In order to accomplish this, you're going to have to put a protect_from_forgery method call in the controller that handles your login. Assuming your /login route maps to the *SessionsController* action *create*:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:create] # Need this to ignore CSRF token
  def create
    # Login logic
  end
end
```

That being said, I wouldn't suggest removing the CSRF token because this will make your application less secure. I would suggest just implementing a special action in your *SessionsController* that just logs them in to their own Session like so:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # Login logic
  end

  def demo_account
    # Logic to create session for demo account
  end
end
```

This way you can just forget about a link that does the POST request and just have a *GET* route that maps /demo_login to *SessionsController*'s *demo_account* action. This would additionally allow this link to be used anywhere as opposed to just in your application (like in an email as one of the previous commenters @allaire suggested). But if you want it to work from a link in your Rails application, then just ignore the part of my answer about the CSRF token.

Comment: Oh Thanks! Interesting, this is working. Im not using the link in the same rails application. The link_to is in the commercial website, and this link makes a POST to the application creating the session. Yes, I have thought about the authenticity_token but surprisingly this is working. How? One think I dont like is that as I am putting my login data (user, password, and remember_me) the user can see in the bottom of the browser the password and username and this may give the user an insecure feeling maybe. Why I cannot send the params in the body of the POST?

Comment: As why the login is working (because of the authenticity_token) I dont know. But I have checked my application logs and when I send the POST it says: WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity, however I can login anyways...

Comment: The perceived security is another reason why I suggested using the approach of creating a separate action to handle it. This limitation of appearing in the URL is just because of how the link_to is implemented. When you set a method on link_to and then click it, jquery-rails creates a form that it then submits as POST request. This is all done in javascript, so I just think they simplified it not to parse out the params that they will just POST to the URL and Rails will take out the params. Otherwise links in browsers can't do POST requests without this kind of override.

Comment: If you want to obfuscate it some more, you can manually write some jQuery on your own the commercial website to handle the post request. This would only be superficial as if someone really wanted to know, they could just dig into your website's source. But if it's only perception your worried about, it would help. In regards to the CSRF token, I'm not sure. I know in my experience I've had requests denied. But I tried it in both development/production on my own app and it worked as you said. Perhaps the default Rails behavior was changed at some point?

Comment: Thanks its more clear now... I like the aproach of creating a new action in my sessions controller. I am using devise as my auth system, do you know how can I add a new method to devise session controller?

Comment: I've never used devise before personally, but this question on SO seems to partly address it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854994/rails-devise-sessions-controller