# Print @class in different view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hi i have made a posts_controller, model and view, is working very good. im using devise to.

I need to echo the "latest" posts on the devise>sesion>new view, how can i do this?

Sorry im learning Rails, and i couldnt find info, maybe because i dont know if @posts is a class, or a method , the way i print posts in view is based on this tutorial

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

What i do is

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.text %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

This cause this error on the devise > sesion > new view.

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Can somebody explain me, im learning and i want to understang, thanks!, i will really appreciate. :D,

In the devise controller, where the def new is i insert this but is still not working

```
 def new
    self.resource = build_resource(nil, :unsafe => true)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))

    @posts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 20)
  end
```

I just added

```
@posts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 20)
```

Why is still throwing the same error.

Comment: in controllers>devise>session there is the session_controller wich is working perfectly . i just need to print posts in the devise session new. .... in the top of controller wich was auto-generated is class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController

Comment: Answer updated. Note the order of operations. the @posts assignment must occur before the `respond_with`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@posts is a class instance variable.

In the way you are trying to use it, @posts would set in the controller and then used in the view.

In your case, you should be setting the @posts variable in the Devise::SessionsController.

The controller is by default in the gem, but you can optionally install it into your application so you can customize it.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854994/rails-devise-sessions-controller) explains how to create a custom SessionsController

EDITED: Your `new` would look something like:

```
def new
  @posts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 20)

  self.resource = build_resource(nil, :unsafe => true)
  clean_up_passwords(resource)
  respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
end
```

Comment: Hey i have one more question, the link to each post is going to domain.com/admin/posts wich is the URL for admin, the url for users is domain.com/posts how can i set this or where in routes.rb i guess. how? can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I just solved using   get '/posts/:id', to: 'posts#show', as: 'post' , hope this help some one.